# How can I retrieve one value from an SQLite table in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve just one single value from my SQLite table. Here is my code:

```
def viewdata():

        idn=studentrecordid.get()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID =?", (idn,))
        values=c.fetchall()
        print(values)
        labwl1=Label(rootF, text=values)
        labwl1.grid(row=6)
```

---

I haven't got a clue how I would go about retrieving just one value so I am currently using the `fetchall()` command.

Comment: Have you read the sqlite documentation? Fetching a single item is well documented in many places.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first row, call `c.fetchone()`. You can call this method repeatedly to exhaust the query's rows, but this is not usually as efficient as iterating over `c.fetchall()`.